# Rails 5: will_paginate gem paginating repeated objects (100 objects of ids 1-10 etc).

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, will-paginate

I have `will_paginate` version `3.1.5` installed on my app and it's doing something funky.

I'm trying to paginate `Books`. I have pagination set up like this in my `books_controller`:

```
def index
  @books = Book.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

But when I visit that page, I notice that the terminal doesn't query 10 books like it should:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2017-05-16 10:28:47 -0700
Processing by BooksController#index as HTML
  Rendering books/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Book Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  Rendered collection of books/_book.html.erb [10 times] (291.7ms)
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "books"
  Rendered books/index.html.erb within layouts/application (389.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 880ms (Views: 849.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

If I inspect `@books` I see that there are 100 `books` in the collection.

```
(byebug) @books.count
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "books"
100
```

But, upon further inspection, It just 10 copies of the first 10 books in the collection. There are only `id`s in the collection are 1-10.

```
(byebug) @books.each { |b| puts b.id }
  Book Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

If I go to the next page I'll just get another 100 results but the `id`s only being 11-20:

```
(byebug) @books.count
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "books"
100
(byebug) @books.each { |b| puts b.id }
  Book Load (4.9ms)  SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 10]]
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

Here are my views:

```
<!-- index.html.erb -->
<h1>Books list:</h1>

<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
        <th>Publication Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="book-list">
      <%= render @books %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="infinite-scrolling">
  <%= will_paginate %>
</div>

<!-- _book.html.erb -->
<% @books.each do |b| %>
<tr>
  <div>
    <td><%= b.id %></td>
    <td><%= b.title %></td>
    <td><%= b.author %></td>
    <td><%= b.genre %></td>
    <td><%= b.pub_date %></td>
  </div>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my issue. I was handling the code the `<%= render @books %>` wrong (I don't use it that much).

I had to change my code in my partial to be more implicit. using `@books.each do |b|` was making things repeat multiple times. Changing my code to this:

```
<!-- _book.html.erb -->
<tr>
  <div>
    <td><%= book.id %></td>
    <td><%= book.title %></td>
    <td><%= book.author %></td>
    <td><%= book.genre %></td>
    <td><%= book.pub_date %></td>
  </div>
</tr>
```

fixed all my issues.